# Where is the official list of differences between pinax 0.9a & 0.7.3

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pinax

Can anyone point me to the **official** list of differences between pinax 0.9a and 0.7.3 please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the blog post for the release, it should answer your question:  http://pinaxproject.com/blog/2011/11/29/pinax-09a2-released/